# How to stop divs from moving below each other when window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper at the top of my web page that spans the whole width.

Within it are a logo (floated left) a navbar (centered) and some social media buttons (floated right) when I minimize the page, I want all the items to remain where they are (relative to the page. i.e. navbar remains centered, social buttons floated right) until they meet each other.

At which point I want them to actually remain where they are (as if it was now a fixed layout) as the page continues to get smaller. Currently, when they meet, the social media buttons move below the navbar and then the navbar moves below the logo.

An example here :

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you mean exactly?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/97nro8lito4jfxf/Screenshot%202013-12-22%2019.13.38.png This is a screenshot of the page. Would seeing my code be more helpful?

Comment: Code is *always* helpful ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use floats then they will wrap to a new line if the space that they need gets bigger than the available space. So if you want to prevent this you need to minimize the wrapper itself.

If you know the width of the three items in the header then you should place a min-width on the header wrapper.

You could also not use floats but choose to let the logo and the social media buttons have  `position: absolute`. The menu n the middle should have a margin left and right as wide as the image / the buttons.

The HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/1/" />
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="social">
        <li>social 1</li>
        <li>social 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.navbar{ 
    position: relative;
    height: 50px; 
    min-width: 370px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
#menu {
    margin: 0 100px 0 50px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 220px;
}
#social {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

This is an example of the absolute approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Yt989/3/

Comment: Giving the navbar margins that are the same width as the image/buttons (i.e. in pixels) makes it fixed, though.

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle that I posted. Is this what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want except I don't want the list items in the central ul to move below each other when the window gets too small.

Comment: Okay, I changed the fiddle. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Yt989/3/